# php implementation of send OTP

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I am trying to implement sendOTP for my website's login verification. I am using the codes available at https://github.com/rwalkover/sendOTPSample-PHP

There are two parts to this; 1. generating the OTP and 2. verifying the OTP 
In the original code, both are done via ajax where php functions are called.

I have been able to integrate the first part succesfully, where the generated OTP is delivered to the mobile phone. I want the verification part to done completely by submitting the form to php.

Please have a look at the sendotp.php file at https://github.com/rwalkover/sendOTPSample-PHP/blob/master/sendotp.php

I have tried to implement the following:
html form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="verifyOtpForm" style="display:none" method = "post" action = "verifyotp.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Enter code:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="oneTimePassword" placeholder="Enter OTP received by SMS" id="oneTimePassword">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" name="verifyOtp" id="verifyOtp" value="Verify OTP" >
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenCode" id="hiddenCode">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenNumber" id="hiddenNumber">
                    </form>
```

verifyotp.php:

```
session_start();
$baseUrl = "https://sendotp.msg91.com/api";
if(isset($_POST['oneTimePassword'])){
    if ($_POST['oneTimePassword'] == $_SESSION["oneTimePassword"]) {

        $data = array("countryCode" => $_POST['hiddenCode'], "mobileNumber" => $_POST['hiddenNumber'], "oneTimePassword" => $_POST['oneTimePassword']);
        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        $ch = curl_init($baseUrl . '/verifyOTP');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            'application-Key: my key goes here'
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response = json_decode($result, true);
        if ($response["status"] == "error") {
            //echo $response["response"]["code"];
            header("location: index.php");
        } else {
            header("location: ../index.php");
        }
    }
}
```

I believe there is a better way to do this. I don't understand anything about curl and what it does. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to verify OTP twice.

First option is to verify OTP from session, and second option is to call sendOTP verify api.

If you want to Verify By sendOTP then use this code :

```
    $baseUrl = "https://sendotp.msg91.com/api";
    if(isset($_POST['oneTimePassword'])){
        $data = array("countryCode" => $_POST['hiddenCode'], "mobileNumber" => $_POST['hiddenNumber'], "oneTimePassword" => $_POST['oneTimePassword']);
        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        $ch = curl_init($baseUrl . '/verifyOTP');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            'application-Key: my key goes here'
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response = json_decode($result, true);
        if ($response["status"] == "error") {
            header("location: index.php");
        } else {
            header("location: ../index.php");
        } 
    }
```

Or if Your want to verify at your end, use this code :

```
if(isset($_POST['oneTimePassword'])){
    if ($_POST['oneTimePassword'] == $_SESSION["oneTimePassword"]) {
            header("location: index.php");
        } else {
            header("location: ../index.php");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this package https://packagist.org/packages/alexgeno/phone-verification. Basic functionality is already there. You can easily extend it if you're restricted to use only "sendotp.msg91.com" as SMS-sending API.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34295903)